# Displaying column name of each table in a specific SQL Server database in MVC C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I've been trying everything to solve this problem, but couldn't get to a solution. This is my first time using MVC.
I have already the query in SQL Server that shows a list of table names and column names of a specific database. This is the query:

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
ORDER BY table_name
```

Is there a way to execute this query in MVC and show the results in the html table?

Comment: I don't see how MVC is related with this query....by executing the query you should get some kind of data collection(DataTables/Lists). And there are numerous ways you can show this data in MVC...

Comment: You have to use linq to get result from this query....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select YOURTABLENAME,YOURCOLUMNNAME
from YOURDATABASENAME.INFORMATION.COLUMNS
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a stored procedure to call it. Try something like this:

```
var tableInfo = db.Database.SqlQuery<tableInfo>("tableInfo_Search");
```

tableInfo_Search would be your sproc's name. Then you can bind that to the table view you wish. If your sproc has parameters that it takes you can just add them after the proc's name.

But then again, your Linq to SQL DataContext already has the table names: `context.Mapping.GetTables()` should be much easier.

Please let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
select TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME 
from <database-name>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Use the above query.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SampleContext dbContext = new SampleContext())
{
   var tablelist = dbContext.Mapping.GetTables();
}
```

You can try the above code.